# Cloud Foundry Org Space

Tags: cloud-foundry

I understand that When an Org and a Space created in Cloud Foundry, it comes with a default resources like disk space and memory. My question is:  Is that means a VM gets created  and mapped to the 'Space' for that Org? Just trying to understand the mapping between the logical Org/space concept to the physical resources. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Orgs and spaces are just things to group resources and assign users by roles to resources. No VM is created when you create an org or space: enough VMs were created in advance to accommodate for the expected usage.
Orgs and spaces to come with a quota, which are limits on how many resources can be consumed within that org/space.

VMs (Diego cells) will already have been created and apps from different orgs and spaces will be distributed evenly over the available cells.

It is possible to reserve some cells for apps from particular spaces (using isolation segments), but here too the creation of VMs is independent of the creation of app and space.